# jquery Date Picker week of the year column

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

jquery date picker provides lot of attributes to play with it but some how I failed to use `showWeek` attribute. As per documentation...

[image: showWeekDescription]

I would like to have a separate column which can show the **Week of the Year**

Please help me out how can I achieve this. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sam / @believe You guys are correct. Even I was trying that. But the jQuery UI version which I was using (`jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js`) is little old.

Downloaded the latest and stable version `jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js` Now it is working like charm. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selector" ).datepicker({
             showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With the base script, I see the week in the first column:

```
$("#date1").datepicker({ showWeek: true });
```

[datepicker image](http://cl.ly/image/2j3M053R2c1h)